# rbenv cannot run gem command

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv

Im using rbenv as my ruby versioning manager, I run these commands:

```
$ rbenv install 2.2.2
$ rbenv global 2.2.2
$ rbenv rehash
$ ruby -v
$ > ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x86_64-darwin11.0]
```

but when I run this command:

```
$ gem -v
```

it returns an error:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv-exec:
```

`/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/gem:` `/Users/mac/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory`
    `/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/0.4.0/libexec/rbenv-exec: line 43:` `/Users/username/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/gem: Undefined error: 0`

What do I miss? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure the problem out. I was using homebrew and uninstalled it. Reinstalled directly and it's working now.